# Regex to find image from content

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the first image from the content. Using Regex

```
<imgs+((width|height|border|classs|id|src|usemap|hspace|vspace)=”[^"]+”s*)+>
```

The function is used as

```
<?php
$content="<img src='s' height='20' >";

preg_match("/<imgs+((width|height|border|classs|id|src|usemap|hspace|vspace)=”[^"]+”s*)+>
/" ,$content,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

But i get a syntax error. I want to handle all possible cases for img tags, how can this be done? I need the src attribute of the tag.

Comment: Is it the quotes? ”? Did you not want '?

Comment: imgs+ ? That's wrong. img/s+ you probably meant.

Comment: Use some sort of HTML parsing library. You cannot use regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @DavidBrabant I think you meant \s+

Comment: I need the value assigned to height|width| source part, between the " quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to catch all possible cases with a regex. HTML generally can not be successfully parsed using only regular expression matching - it's just too complex.

You will need to use a proper html parser, or limit yourself to a subset of possible solutions.

Comment: I know, i would like to handle atleast some commone cases.